# How to decompile /usr/bin/ls

Tags: disassembly, decompilation, ghidra, decompile, decompiler

How to decompile the following assembly instructions ?

Note: this could be reproduced using */usr/bin/ls* [binary](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/promach/fa989fbd4ff74dcbed37aff0d39d1a9f/raw/3ca6889632b2f322fefa6060b6725b4832a98c73/ls) inside ghidra

[image: ghidra decompilation of ls]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the decompiler view it cleary states there's no function. Decompiler works when you have one - it shows code of a function.

So, if that's the beginning of a function (it might be) just create it by pressing <kbd>F</kbd> (or right click, `Create Function`) while your cursor is on the line that is the beginning of this function. After that the decompiler view should populate with code.

Comment: Thanks, now I have [this other issue](https://i.imgur.com/GGmugEs.png)

Comment: It's difficult to understand just from the picture what the issue is. If it's related to this one - update your question. If not - create a new one.

Comment: it is unrelated, but the question remains the same on how to decompile /usr/bin/ls

Comment: @kevin you shouldn't have to do anything at all to get it to decompile, how do you know you need to decompile this specific part?

Comment: @multithr3at3d "how do you know you need to decompile this specific part?" <-- what do you mean ? Why ?

Comment: @kevin like, how did you get to that specific address? In your second image, it doesn't look like you're in a section with actual instructions.

Comment: @multithr3at3d the second image is PLT entry.  Do I need to decompile PLT entry ?

Comment: @kevin: the PLT is a *[table](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/ELF/zSeries/lzsabi0_zSeries/x2251.html)*. What do you exactly expect to get from 'decompiling' it?

Answer (score 3):

Kevin,

`ls` comes in coreutils. The best way to experiment with these programs is to download and manually build the binaries (in this way you can give your favorite options like -g, -O3 during compilation).

Anyways, coming back to your question, assuming you want to decompile /usr/bin/ls (that's what I get from your comments on Pawel's answer), then open ghidra gui, analyse the binary, click on file -> export program -> and export as a C/C++ file.

Comment: Why export it when you can view the decompilation within Ghidra?

Comment: yes you can do that. But, it is much easier for a beginner to examine the exported code, as you can get globally defined structures, variables, even type information (ghidra constructs typedefs for custome types like undefined4 -> int), in a single unit. Thus you don't have to jump around and click through the references to check the information.