# how to infer data type in ghidra decompilation result

Tags: decompilation, ghidra, decompile, decompiler

how to infer data type in ghidra decompilation result for */usr/bin/ls* ?

[image: data type]

Answer (score 1):

Kevin,

As I answered on your last [question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25030/how-to-decompile-usr-bin-ls):

open ghidra gui, analyse the binary, click on file -> export program -> and export as a C/C++ file.

In this file, ghidra constructs possible typedefs for you.

For e.g. `typedef unsigned char    undefined1;`

So, you'll know the possible type of this object. In your particular case, it constructs (assuming a stripped binary):

`typedef unsigned long    undefined8;`

But, note that these types are just estimates and could be different than the original source code (in case of user defined functions).

Comment: Could you be more exact on data type ?

Comment: no, you can't as data type inference is still an unsolved problem

Comment: What do you man by "unsolved" ?

This [decompilation result](https://i.imgur.com/7AHCrCL.png) has so many _undefined8_

Comment: i.e. correct type recovery from stripped binaries is not fully possible yet. If you get undefineds then it is possible that the decompiler is not able to detect correct types and marked it as a custom type